# Run an EJB application in AWS lambda

Tags: java, aws-lambda, ejb

We have one customized java framework based on EJB. Using that framework as a dependency (means extending the functionality), we have some applications (so indirectly, these applications are also EJB). This application is hosted on one on-prem jboss server.

Now, we want to remove this on-prem server and move this application to AWS lambda, because this application is only used once a day (i mean call to this application comes only once a day).
Moreover, the criteria is not to touch existing application code. we can write some classes to add lambda handler or something but we can modify existing application code or architecture. (some limitations i really wanted to re-write but no option).

can someone please suggest if it is possible to run EJB based JAVA application (which is hosted on on-prem jboss today) from AWS-lambda? (i mean, can we host it on lambda?).

This is the starting point of that EJB application:

```
package packagename;

//various imports here
import javax.ejb.*;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;

@MessageDriven(messageListenerInterface=MessageListener.class,
    activationConfig = {
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "java:global/queue/queuename"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="hostName", propertyValue="${jms.queue.manager.host}"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="port", propertyValue="${jms.queue.manager.port}"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="channel", propertyValue="${jms.queue.manager.channel}"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="queueManager", propertyValue="${jms.queue.manager.name}"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="useJNDI", propertyValue="true")
    })
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class BatchInvoker extends BatchInvokerServiceMDB {

    @EJB
    public ImportPlannedCoursesJob importPlannedCoursesJob;

}
```

Comment: [Quarkus](https://code.quarkus.io/) does not support this currently.  However, while [Thorntail](https://thorntail.io/generator/) does it's unclear how long Thorntail will be supported.  But it will create a single `.jar` that can run in Lambda.  I've used Thorntail on multiple Lambdas.  As @HoratiuJeflea indicates your initial startup time will not be great but if you're only running this once a day you should be fine.

Comment: If you are using EJB-Stateful Session Bean then i guess its not possible as the lambda is stateless. Its worth exploring Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Mine is EJB-Stateless MessageDrivenBean....

Comment: @VijayGurunanee :  Did you succeed in running EJB using lambda?

Comment: No Sir... we didn't... so, we changed from lambda to AWS Batch

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible, but JBoss has a very slow startup time.

In Lambda, startup will happen very ofter (one for every parallel call). Also the containers are ephemeral (they are closed after a few minutes/hours).

There is also the timeout constraint (max 15 minutes timeout). So if it take 10 minutes for JBoss to start, you are only left with 5 minutes to execute the request.

Also, is such a delay considered acceptable? I would suggest maybe another solution - [Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/)

Comment: Mine is EJB-Stateless MessageDrivenBean.... have uploaded the zip as per your suggestion and lambda didn't give any error... However, i am confused with how can i run it... let me update the question with the point where it is starting.. Plz suggest how can i trigger it..